# Read xlsx attachments from Gmail message

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail

I have a module in my API that reads messages with attachments and till today I faced .csv attachments only. Now I need to read .xlsx attachment as well and my module can't execute it, because the content is not base64.

Is it possible to do it? For now my .xlsx file contains only one sheet, so, at least for now, 'tab problem' is not relevant for me.

For now, I use Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 to do read .csv attachment

Comment: I can provide my code if it is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Reading attachments is one thing and opening an excel file is entirely something else.

You can read any attachment no matter what its type is (image, pdf, excel, etc) and for this, you may code it yourself, use one o many available libraries. I would suggest https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1/ which is developed by Google itself.

once you downloaded the attachments, based on their types, you may decide what to do with them. you may ignore pdfs, save images, open excel files, and read their content. there are also lots of NuGet packages for reading excel files (you can search on the web), I used to use EPPlus which was free, but now it is commercial and very expensive, I now use ExcelDataReader, but of course, there are lots of libraries both free and commercial that you can use. You may also use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel which I find it hard to use.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that I want to open it. I read the content of the file, but don't download/open it

Comment: well, you need to download the attachments and open the excel ones.